# How do you match cans of white paint to walls

Tags: paint, patching-drywall

I have ~15 cans of whiteish paint in my basement but I don't know which cans go with which walls and ceilings.  My plan for matching them is to open each can, stir, and paint a swatch on something.  Then I can compare the swatches to each surface directly.

Is there any reason why that plan wouldn't work or any tips from anyone who's had to do this before?  What should the swatches be painted on?  I was thinking something thin, light colored, and sturdy so it can be held as close as possible to the existing surfaces.  Maybe card stock or foam core board. There would not be a need to prime the swatch material, correct?

Comment: Actual cans with any age to speak of on them are probably contaminated by rust by now, among other issues. Really tightly sealed plastic containers can buy a few years.

Comment: Moral of the story - mark the cans when you buy them, Transfer that info to smaller plastic containers with less hadspace when the job is done, or stick with **one** "shade of white" if not using readily identifiable colors.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/2598/

Comment: Old paint may no longer match in color *or* sheen.

Comment: Paint the whole room... any can you pick is a perfect match.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work very well.

First of all, if the paint is old, forget about it. A quick search says 2 - 10 years, but it can vary quite a bit depending on the quality of the paint, storage temperature and other factors.

The second issue is weathering. Obviously paint inside doesn't have the same issues as outside - a lot less light, no rain, no extreme temperatures, etc. But still, paint will change color a bit over time, enough that a freshly painted section may not match an existing wall closely enough to be "good". Not as much of an issue if you repaint an entire wall at a time or a large section that is broken up by other things (e.g., door, fireplace, etc.).

The next issue is primer. If you don't put a layer of primer on your swatch before the paint, there may be a slightly different result.

The last issue is that fresh paint looks different from fully dried paint. If you paint a swatch today and it seems dry tomorrow, it may still change color for several days (lighter or darker) as it finishes drying, which will affect how it compares to your walls.

Comment: Against that: I do have some paint that had held it's color pretty darned well during the ten years between when I bought it and used half of it, and when I used it to cover some later work. After feathering the edges and letting everything fully dry, I can't see where the old paint and newer paint meet. So if you have leftovers from the previous paint job and they seem to still be in good condition, it's certainly worth trying them. Stir very well first, of course. If it doesn't wind up being a close enough match, you're no worse off...

Comment: @keshlam No harm in trying - worst case you paint over the whole wall with fresh paint. I'm pointing out the problems with trying to match up a bunch of white-ish paints.

Comment: True. Whites have different shades, different brightness, different surface finishes (matte, semi-matte, glossy, the rest of that)... The closest to a consistent pure bright white I've found is Ceiling White, and even that won't reliably match up from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy 8x10 double sided foam test boards from the paint store.  Their surface is designed for painting, they don't need priming and don't absorb the paint.  They are a good size for visual testing.  You can even cut them in half to get four colors per board.

Ignore all the advice about paint aging and the difficulty of color matching.   Swatch all 15 of your paints, try them all out wherever you need to make a repair or patch.    Pick the best one for any repair.  Best case it'll work great.   More likely, you paint a whole wall: extend the repair to the nearest edges (inner or outer corners, etc) and those are VERY forgiving of minor differences.    Worst case, but this is soooo unlikely ... but worst case none of them works at all and you have to rip a sample off your wall and have it color matched at the store.

Answer (score 1):

Better to do what the pros would do--

> My plan for matching them is to open each can, stir, and paint a swatch on something. Then I can compare the swatches to each surface directly.

-- OK, yeah, that actually. That's what the pros would do :) They'd prepare some "drift cards" by priming them with appropriate primer, so the substrate is stable (isn't color- or texture-altered by the swatch material's interaction with the paint).

### The problem with old paint, though

EPA and California's mini-EPA are rather fond of "low-hanging fruit". They go after categories of emissions that create the most overall smog.  They started with cars obviously, and worked their way down to architectural paints.  There, they said that paints must have very low VOC - and that pretty much mandated emulsion ("latex", no latex in it) paints. And then, they cranked it down *even further* to where there isn't enough VOC in latex paint anymore to suppress certain organisms like mold.

So here we are at your old paint.  Lots of people open up old paint, it's stinky (we expect that; *it's paint*) and paint it on walls. Then, the stink does not disburse after a few hours as you expect with latex.  It stays and stays and never leaves.  Mold or something bred in that paint can, and it's on the walls. The stories are consistent: overcoating doesn't help, everything they try doesn't help, and the ultimate cure is to remove the offending material, which is now under a few layers of desperate experiments.  Not a happy scene.

So yes, make your swatch cards, make 2-3 maybe of each color. Take care to look at the formula label on the can, if the formula data is identical on two cans, you don't need to make two swatches.

Mold isn't going to affect color-truth much, and if the smell is irksome, wait a few weeks for full cure, and stick it in a Ziploc bag.  A lot of paints need air or moisture-in-the-air to cure.  Curing is not drying, that's the difference between paint and whitewash.

Then, take your swatches down to your trusted paint shop, and let them stick it under the XRite scanner and develop a paint formula for it.  They can do that on the spot.   **Then, paint your house with the new paint you buy to that formula.**

With the old paint, either do as your city tells you to do re: household hazardous waste, and it's often recycled or used for outdoor low-risk applications where mold doesn't matter, like graffiti cover-ups. Or, as an old friend advises, "Paint something you don't want, then throw it away".  The VOCs and other compounds are still *far* more harmful soaked into a landfill than released into the air.